# download zip files in php using headers

Tags: php, zip

I have following PHP Script for downloading the zip files:

```
header("Content-length:".filesize($archive_file_name));
header('Content-Type: application/zip'); // ZIP file
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloadpackage.zip"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($archive_file_name);
exit();
```

But it doesn't force the download the zip file instead, it shows the lots of unusual characters like below:

PK[�FA����#�X$D:\voice_06101243342pm014771957.wav�|�s]�y���b�CI\��{2m��M'�Eibu2\@B��܋{� 6b# $H,\@��:��Z�(q�����ә���Y��q�����,� ���� d��y��O�tp$PĽg��w}��}�r֯[7�u�"w���|o�7/Z��ˋ^Z������Ң�ZTZ\S|N����c�X8��c�X8��c�X8��c�X8��c�X8���۲,��a�oA*=ە���do:��|ˉ'rb�|�L2�*^�:q׵}/��\�s�Z?��G�[��=ϗ?

I have also placed the below code before the headers function :

```
if (headers_sent()) 
{
  // HTTP header has already been sent
  return false;
}
// clean buffer(s)
while (ob_get_level() > 0)
{
   ob_end_clean();
}
```

This ignore to display those character and zip is also not force to download. I couldn't figure out the problem, please help me, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your php file UTF-8 with BOM? Why do you have 2 content types headers?

Comment: actually I have only one its mistake

Comment: For the four headers you use, please, for each one on it's own, explain a) what it does and b) why you decided to use it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this with PHP? Why not allow your web server to do its job and serve the zip files?

Comment: i got same issue, you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
PK[�FA����#�X$D:\voice_06101243342pm014771957.wav�|
�s]�y���b�CI\��{2m��M'�Eibu2\@B��܋{� 6b# 
$H,\@��:��Z�(q�����ә���Y��q�����,�     ���� d��y��O�tp$PĽg��w}��}
�r֯[7�u�"w���|o�7/Z��ˋ^Z������Ң�ZTZ\S|N����c�X8��c�X8��c�X8��c�X8��c�X8���۲,��a�oA*
=ە���do:��|ˉ'rb�|�L2�*^�:q׵}/��\�s�Z?��G�[��=ϗ?
```

This is your zip file.

You are a receiving a zip file and there's nothing wrong, you just need to correct your php processing script because apparently it is processing it as plain text/string.

Note the `PK` at the start, zip files start with 'PK` data. Test yourself by opening any zip file with a hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your header:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple function I use to download files:

```
function _download ($file_name) {
  $src = fopen($this->download_path . $file_name,'r') or die("\n\n ========= Could not download $file_name\n");
  $dest = fopen($file_name,'w');
  stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest);
}
```