# PHP Script to download files in zip

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm setting up a script on my server that uses some GET variables sent by a user to decides which files to include in a zip that then gets returned to the user. The ZIP file is created dynamically by the script and will always have the name myZip.zip.

If I potentially have 100 users calling the script at the same time, and each user may have different files included in the zip, will this work?

Thanks!

example of script:

```
<?php

     $fileA = 'fileA.xml';
     $fileB = 'fileB.xml';
     $fileC = 'fileC.xml';

     $filesToSend = array();

     if(conditionA) {

        array_push($filesToSend, $fileA);
     }

    if(conditionB) {

        array_push($filesToSend, $fileB);
     }

     if(conditionC) {

        array_push($filesToSend, $fileC);
     }

     if(count($filesToSend) > 0) {

        $zipname = "myZip.zip";
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $res = $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

        if ($res === TRUE) {

            foreach ($filesToSend as $file) {

                $zip->addFile($file);
            }
        }
        else {

            echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
        }

        $zip->close();

        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header('Content-length: '.filesize($zipname));
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($zipname));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($zipname);
        @unlink($file);
    }
    else {
        echo "nothing new";
        echo $modifiedDate;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should create a unique file name on the server for each user, then serve it with "myZip.zip" for every one

Comment: Nope. you're creating an on-disk .zip file, so ALL of your users will be stomping on each other. Use  `uniqid()` to generate a unique filename for each request and use that id for the on-disk filename. You can still serve up "myZip.zip" in the download headeres, e.g. `Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myZip.zip`

Answer (score -1):

These links may help you:

1. [Using headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761812/download-zip-files-in-php-using-headers)
2. [Creating zip file in PHP](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php)

Comment: Link only answers and not acceptable. The second link does not even have an answer or one accepted by the community.